RDP doesn't work over WAN
so a few days ago I noticed that RDP stopped working over WAN for me. Before this it worked without any issues and I didn't change any settings. Port checker tools show that the port is open. I have tried disabling the firewall in case that was causing any issues but that didn't do anything.
EDIT:
To clarify I'm trying to connect to a computer on my home network. I'm using a computer on a different network or a phone with cellular data to test if I can connect. The port being used is 3389. I have also talked with my ISP and they claim that they aren't blocking anything. I can also access other services that I have forwarded on the same machine.

How is your WAN configured?

Are we talking about incoming RDP or outgoing RDP? And if incoming, how are you testing it?
